# Planning a roadtrip from Sydney to Perth on my VW Golf

Tags: sydney, perth

As the title suggests, I am planning a roadtrip from Sydney to Perth. Would appreciate any pointers on what to be done or any tips needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about constructing itineraries are off-topic here, but I will say: That's an awfully long trip (+4000 km), a lot of it through areas where there is nothing of interest (unless you're interested in sand).

Comment: @Godly George Do you have any specific concerns or questions? Your question is likely to be closed if not.

Comment: @Henrik I think you are showing a bias in your opinion of how interesting a long road trip through desolate areas may be. There is beauty in areas packed full of different things, but there is also beauty in sameness.